# How to compute matrices to high powers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I find the following matrix raised to the power of $279$ without using eigenvalues?

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -1\\\ 1 & 0 & -1\\\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Eigenvalues are the natural approach to this, but instead you can try working out the first few powers and guessing a general case - then proving it with induction. In this case you don't really need induction: work out $A^4$, and see how that helps.

Comment: Why without eigenvalues? The powers of some particular matrix form a pattern you can recognize and prove. You could try with this one.

Comment: I have $A^4$ is the identity matrix, but I'm not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: if $A^4$ is the identity then the sequence of powers cycles.

Comment: My first intuition when it comes to "arbitrary powers" of matrices is to diagonalize.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum So, if the powers from 1, 2, 3, 4 cycle then if we have 279 as the power, 276 is a factor of four, cycled 69 times, so A^3 should be equivalent to A^279. Is that right?

Comment: Thats the logic, yes.  Just like raising $i$ to arbitrary powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that this matrix is a companion matrix, so we can read off its characteristic polynomial to be 
$$
x^3+x^2+x+1
$$
By Cayley-Hamilton, 
$$
A^3+A^2+A+I=0\implies (A-I)(A^3+A^2+A+I)=0\\
\implies A^4=I
$$
So, 
$$
A^{279}=A^{276}A^3=A^3
$$

Answer (score 1):

The observation that $A^4=I$ is indeed useful.

$$279 = 4(69)+3$$

Hence $$A^{279}=A^{4(69)+3}=(A^4)^{69}A^3=I^{69}A^3=A^3.$$

Remark: Your matrix is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

$$I+A+A^2+A^3=0$$

$$(I-A)(I+A+A^2+A^3)=0$$

$$I-A^4=0$$

$$A^4=I$$

Comment: sorry, I saw your edit after I had posted my answer :(, +1

Comment: well, we get to confirm our answer. =)